# PHP Session variables from POST

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm foreach-ing through my POST variables (though I'm using the $_REQUEST)

I want to put all the variables into their own Session variables, but it's simply not working.
Does this look incorrect to anyone?

```
<?php

foreach ($_REQUEST as $posted_name => $posted_value){

 $_SESSION[$posted_name].' = '.$posted_value;

}
?>
```

I am including the session_start() in another part of my script.  Above, of course.

Comment: add `session_start();` and change it to `$_SESSION[$posted_name] = $posted_value;` then see what happens..

Comment: $_SESSION is special. Not all characters are allowed as top level array keys, unlike all other php arrays. Better to do *$_SESSION['requestVars'] = $_REQUEST;*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big problem with this:

```
$_SESSION[$posted_name].' = '.$posted_value;
```

You don't need to use the string concatenation `.` to set a session value.  This line simple evaluates to a string and doesn't save anything in the `$_SESSION` superglobal.

Try this instead

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value){
  $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: You were right.  The problem was the concatenation. I made that change it worked perfectly.  Good catch!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you didn't call this function yet:

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You intended to write this instead:

```
$_SESSION[$posted_name] = $posted_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you concatenating a string or are you setting a value?

Try

```
$_SESSION[$posted_name] = $posted_value;
```

and what @colighto said.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `session_start()`

Your final code should look like

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach ($_POST as $posted_name => $posted_value) {
    $_SESSION[$posted_name] = $posted_value;
    //You added unnecessary commenting here
}
?>
```